# Improve time of looping comparisons and assignments in pandas or numpy

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, loops

I have 2 df:

df1

| X | Y |
| --- | --- |
| a | c |
| b | d |

df2

| Z | Q |
| --- | --- |
| i | f |
| j | h |

The number of the rows and columns is undefined.

I need to compare X and Z: when an element in X is equal to an element in Z (suppose a is equal to j), the corrisponding value of a in Y (c) becomes equal to the corrisponding value of j in Q (h).

Like so:

```
for k in range(0, df1['X']:
   for p in range(0, df2['Z']):
      if df1.iloc[k]['X'] == df2.iloc[p]['Y']:
           df1.at[k,'Y'] = df2.iloc[p]['Q']
```

Obviously with large dataframes this procedure is unsustainable. Anyone know how to speed everything up? I was reading that numpy offers vectorizations. How could this be done? Thanks for the help!

Comment: EDIT   if df1.iloc[k]['X'] == df2.iloc[p]['Y']:     ------->      if df1.iloc[k]['X'] == df2.iloc[p]['Z']:

Answer (score 1):

Simply do:

```py
df1["Y"] = np.where(df1.X == df2.Z, df2.Q, df1.Y)
```

Comment: Always returns the case in which the two cells are not equal, a match never occurs and it is impossible because the "base" code returns matches that actually exist

Comment: it appears to be comparing elements on the same row only, and not a nested loop